# Using XSLT Filter some files from Heat output file based on Environment input

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, windows-installer, heat

I have some files which need to be eliminated from .WXS  based on given Input of environment like dev,prod which will be passed as a property to Heat.exe. Based on that I need to filter out or remove some files from Fragment.WXS after harvesting through XSLT transformation. For Example if the xslt template is for dev then I need all the files whose Source file doesn't contain .UAT,.Prod,.Test   . I also need the command that need to used to execute transformation also with Heat.

Please see below some of the components from Heat generated output

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
                <Fragment>
                    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
                       <Directory Id="dir8EF11DA0EAFBFCB7A0B81343D3750C8B" Name="SCBUDirect" />
                    </DirectoryRef>
                </Fragment>
                <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="SCBUDirect">

        <Component Id="cmpE3B75974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{CA810124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
        <File Id="fil85729F855FDD131D6161043C08CB4543" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_dev_ConnectionStrings.config" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="cmpERG5974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{ERGT50124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
            <File Id="fil8574324425555FDD131D6161043C08CB4543" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_prod_ConnectionStrings.config" />
         </Component>

<Component Id="cmp51A6C4030B563BC4A64DA99AED42D978" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{CF063EF0-6926-4D21-B89D-BD71E0E926F7}">
                <File Id="fil1494493122AA1F38F8D2C11F93A8D4E8" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment.config" />
            </Component>


        <Component Id="cmpDF354EF7DC6C98108D05886911231011" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{F912A8C7-1226-49D6-897F-1878A1607B16}">
        <File Id="fil1058EF5A5E46590311096FFC704CD243" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="cmpD84FEB6CD3B1AE3534AA6B94CF5065C8" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{8BEBA112-9967-4DD9-96FC-25A879C5D6FA}">
        <File Id="filE0D63A4EC6CCCF6E9C06A91E04EA87E7" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.prod" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="cmp0B6A1EF1380A825CC1F3894FAA38CC0B" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{60C807BD-142C-4C1F-8366-DC297657AB0A}">
        <File Id="fil20F28B0827462F414C432783951DD049" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.test" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="cmp80CFA73AA353BE789D4539008E7F3516" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{0B3FA0E7-8F66-408C-944F-DAA0A847B6C4}">
        <File Id="fil2B292A388045FDF49475C9F6C5D144D1" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.uat" />
        </Component>

     <Component Id="cmpE1C2EEC551696DCE99C2CAB9ED013C54" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{A3D766EE-A488-468A-A7BF-DDB507B21299}">
                    <File Id="fil2F90622E603C0AF703A504C3DE3A6201" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.config" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpEBF2150BC59E378124B87AF387DA5519" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{16CF5D16-A551-4184-9E9D-772A9277941A}">
                    <File Id="fil9241DCC3F781240AD979AAF25BF020F5" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.CSR.config" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpA8F307EAB3BEB1352C23666A8E11D981" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{3A42EC95-3DE5-4BB8-870F-E4AE8C8B1AE0}">
                    <File Id="fil8A99AE4CB701995838FD078019546D30" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Prod.config.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpB64314E8A44B127FAE8A6CBAAF9AA052" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{450B216D-7A3D-40EF-A41D-AAB2FA65BC5D}">
                    <File Id="fil0F1FCF642AF4B0D8A101964BCAFCA227" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Prod.CSR.config.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpD59E44F90B1003A9D3FEEE194F8AA63D" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{94AA1663-5043-4DA1-A60D-50FFEDED6B7A}">
                    <File Id="filCA238418D1A725B1303D44003BEE495E" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Test.config.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp1AF2C8707EBD76A179C1CE20515E0A9B" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{42342DFE-227C-4F70-B2E9-B9422DEA45AE}">
                    <File Id="filAB15496223BAA05CC1CCFED05F52E902" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Test.CSR.config.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp89433C61AF95511BE1BC8121DAAAA401" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{DDB6E815-9946-4744-8D1A-E4BE3D09EC2E}">
                    <File Id="filC0041C051A21C3705C9417015F51ACCC" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.UAT.config.xml" />
                </Component>

                <Component Id="cmp131FA57DB66446A7226E0236B8ACAAFD" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{6CA4CE62-33FD-4BF9-8E43-1A079983D492}">
                    <File Id="fil42A0BC81342E575F8EA9F004A065CCA4" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.UAT.CSR.config.xml" />
                </Component>
     <Component Id="cmp3B36FD232E0AAD653B9259D5F2AC60A2" Directory="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Guid="{BF4A808E-AFBD-4F43-8F90-20E38639C8BD}">
                    <File Id="filFD59C7E39C8BCA47D7ECEA7EBCA4E8FF" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\controls\ReferAFriend\ReferAFriendInfo.ascx" />
                </Component>

        </ComponentGroup>
        </Fragment>

                <Fragment>
                    <DirectoryRef Id="dir19836A556979704BCD883A1A4BC5ACCA">
                       <Directory Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Name="App_Config" />
                    </DirectoryRef>
                </Fragment> 
               <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A">
                <Directory Id="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Name="Deployment" />
            </DirectoryRef>
              </Fragment>
     <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="dir0370A1E873AC03CA5FA01FB090FBCEF4">
                <Directory Id="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Name="ReferAFriend" />
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>    
            </Wix>
```

And here is my xslt file have come up with which need to made to work.

```
   ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

          <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

          <!--<!–Identity Transform–>-->
          <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>

          <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
          <xsl:key name="config-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'TestBuild_prod')]" use="@Id"/>
          <!--<!–Match and ignore TestBuild_prod files for dev Environment similarly vice-versa for prod Environment –>-->
          <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('config-search', @Id)]"/>
          <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('config-search', @Id)]"/>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And after transformation the fragment.WXS file looks like  below if the input is "dev"

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
                <Fragment>
                    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
                       <Directory Id="dir8EF11DA0EAFBFCB7A0B81343D3750C8B" Name="SCBUDirect" />
                    </DirectoryRef>
                </Fragment>

        <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="SCBUDirect">

        <Component Id="cmpE3B75974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{CA810124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
        <File Id="fil85729F855FDD131D6161043C08CB4543" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_dev_ConnectionStrings.config" />
        </Component>


       <Component Id="cmp51A6C4030B563BC4A64DA99AED42D978" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{CF063EF0-6926-4D21-B89D-BD71E0E926F7}">
            <File Id="fil1494493122AA1F38F8D2C11F93A8D4E8" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment.config" />
        </Component>


        <Component Id="cmpDF354EF7DC6C98108D05886911231011" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{F912A8C7-1226-49D6-897F-1878A1607B16}">
        <File Id="fil1058EF5A5E46590311096FFC704CD243" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="cmpE1C2EEC551696DCE99C2CAB9ED013C54" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{A3D766EE-A488-468A-A7BF-DDB507B21299}">
                <File Id="fil2F90622E603C0AF703A504C3DE3A6201" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.config" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="cmpEBF2150BC59E378124B87AF387DA5519" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{16CF5D16-A551-4184-9E9D-772A9277941A}">
                <File Id="fil9241DCC3F781240AD979AAF25BF020F5" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.CSR.config" />
       </Component>

     <Component Id="cmp3B36FD232E0AAD653B9259D5F2AC60A2" Directory="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Guid="{BF4A808E-AFBD-4F43-8F90-20E38639C8BD}">
                <File Id="filFD59C7E39C8BCA47D7ECEA7EBCA4E8FF" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\controls\ReferAFriend\ReferAFriendInfo.ascx" />
     </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
                <Fragment>
                    <DirectoryRef Id="dir19836A556979704BCD883A1A4BC5ACCA">
                   <Directory Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Name="App_Config" />
                    </DirectoryRef>
                </Fragment>     
               <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A">
            <Directory Id="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Name="Deployment" />
        </DirectoryRef>
             </Fragment> 
 <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir0370A1E873AC03CA5FA01FB090FBCEF4">
            <Directory Id="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Name="ReferAFriend" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment> 
 </Wix>
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Question is How to achieve to filter certain files from WXS file using XSLT .But the one above XSLT transformation not working and second thing  is ,I want also the command which can used to transform .WXS file using XSLT to get required output (new file of .WXS)

Comment: Please, edit the question and specify this there. Also, provide a complete, well-formed source XML document and the exact result you want from the transformation, when applied on that XML document.

Comment: Hi Dimitre I have edited the Question please let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Good... we're much closer now. The last XML you posted above is described as the actual output of your XSLT, not the desired output. Am I understanding that correctly? If so, what is the desired output? Please edit your question to show that.

Comment: There are lot more components which I have not added,But I will add one or more components to Source Fragment.WXS and that should not be filtered out and need to be also in Resulted transformed XML.

Comment: Hi @LarsH thankls for the reply .I have added some more components ,and I have provided actual output required .Please let me know this works for the solution provided.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Initially I thought that the first block of XML you posted above ("Heat generated output") was input to the XSLT, but now I think it's output from the XSLT. Maybe. Could you clarify that? Also, I'm still not clear on whether the last XML you posted is required output, or actual output. Ideally, we need three XML samples: the input to the XSLT, the current (actual) output from XSLT, and the desired (required) output. Right now you have two of those but I'm not sure which ones. However if @Daniel's solution works for you then you're done.

Comment: First block is part of the output of Heat.exe . And the last one is the fragment.wxs should look like after transformation and will be used for MSI installation.Not sure of yours desired and actualfile

Comment: Dimitre or LarsH can you please revisit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like it does what you want. There is an `xsl:param` with the default value of `dev`. You can modify this to control which `Component` elements are kept.

**XML Input**

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="dir8EF11DA0EAFBFCB7A0B81343D3750C8B" Name="SCBUDirect" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="SCBUDirect">

            <Component Id="cmpE3B75974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{CA810124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
                <File Id="fil85729F855FDD131D6161043C08CB4543" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_dev_ConnectionStrings.config" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmpERG5974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{ERGT50124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
                <File Id="fil8574324425555FDD131D6161043C08CB4543" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_prod_ConnectionStrings.config" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmp51A6C4030B563BC4A64DA99AED42D978" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{CF063EF0-6926-4D21-B89D-BD71E0E926F7}">
                <File Id="fil1494493122AA1F38F8D2C11F93A8D4E8" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment.config" />
            </Component>


            <Component Id="cmpDF354EF7DC6C98108D05886911231011" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{F912A8C7-1226-49D6-897F-1878A1607B16}">
                <File Id="fil1058EF5A5E46590311096FFC704CD243" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmpD84FEB6CD3B1AE3534AA6B94CF5065C8" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{8BEBA112-9967-4DD9-96FC-25A879C5D6FA}">
                <File Id="filE0D63A4EC6CCCF6E9C06A91E04EA87E7" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.prod" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmp0B6A1EF1380A825CC1F3894FAA38CC0B" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{60C807BD-142C-4C1F-8366-DC297657AB0A}">
                <File Id="fil20F28B0827462F414C432783951DD049" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.test" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmp80CFA73AA353BE789D4539008E7F3516" Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Guid="{0B3FA0E7-8F66-408C-944F-DAA0A847B6C4}">
                <File Id="fil2B292A388045FDF49475C9F6C5D144D1" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.uat" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmpE1C2EEC551696DCE99C2CAB9ED013C54" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{A3D766EE-A488-468A-A7BF-DDB507B21299}">
                <File Id="fil2F90622E603C0AF703A504C3DE3A6201" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpEBF2150BC59E378124B87AF387DA5519" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{16CF5D16-A551-4184-9E9D-772A9277941A}">
                <File Id="fil9241DCC3F781240AD979AAF25BF020F5" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.CSR.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpA8F307EAB3BEB1352C23666A8E11D981" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{3A42EC95-3DE5-4BB8-870F-E4AE8C8B1AE0}">
                <File Id="fil8A99AE4CB701995838FD078019546D30" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Prod.config.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpB64314E8A44B127FAE8A6CBAAF9AA052" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{450B216D-7A3D-40EF-A41D-AAB2FA65BC5D}">
                <File Id="fil0F1FCF642AF4B0D8A101964BCAFCA227" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Prod.CSR.config.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpD59E44F90B1003A9D3FEEE194F8AA63D" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{94AA1663-5043-4DA1-A60D-50FFEDED6B7A}">
                <File Id="filCA238418D1A725B1303D44003BEE495E" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Test.config.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp1AF2C8707EBD76A179C1CE20515E0A9B" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{42342DFE-227C-4F70-B2E9-B9422DEA45AE}">
                <File Id="filAB15496223BAA05CC1CCFED05F52E902" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Test.CSR.config.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp89433C61AF95511BE1BC8121DAAAA401" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{DDB6E815-9946-4744-8D1A-E4BE3D09EC2E}">
                <File Id="filC0041C051A21C3705C9417015F51ACCC" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.UAT.config.xml" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmp131FA57DB66446A7226E0236B8ACAAFD" Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Guid="{6CA4CE62-33FD-4BF9-8E43-1A079983D492}">
                <File Id="fil42A0BC81342E575F8EA9F004A065CCA4" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.UAT.CSR.config.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp3B36FD232E0AAD653B9259D5F2AC60A2" Directory="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Guid="{BF4A808E-AFBD-4F43-8F90-20E38639C8BD}">
                <File Id="filFD59C7E39C8BCA47D7ECEA7EBCA4E8FF" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\controls\ReferAFriend\ReferAFriendInfo.ascx" />
            </Component>

        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir19836A556979704BCD883A1A4BC5ACCA">
            <Directory Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Name="App_Config" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment> 
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A">
            <Directory Id="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Name="Deployment" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir0370A1E873AC03CA5FA01FB090FBCEF4">
            <Directory Id="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Name="ReferAFriend" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>    
</Wix>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="type" select="'dev'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wi:Component">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$type='dev'">
                <xsl:variable name="source" select="translate(wi:File/@Source,$upper,$lower)"/>
                <!--Note: These are not exact matches. contains() checks to see if the string is anywhere in $source.-->                
                <!--.test - substring($source,string-length($source) - 4,4)-->
                <xsl:if test="not(contains($source,'.test')) and not(contains($source,'.uat')) and not(contains($source,'.prod'))">
                    <xsl:call-template name="ident"/>
                </xsl:if>               
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$type='blah'">
                <!--Copy xsl:if from above and modify for 'blah' types.-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--If you need to output anything by default, it would go here. Otherwise, xsl:otherwise 
                is not needed and can be removed.-->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
         <Directory Id="dir8EF11DA0EAFBFCB7A0B81343D3750C8B" Name="SCBUDirect"/>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
      <ComponentGroup Id="SCBUDirect">
         <Component Id="cmpE3B75974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F"
                    Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A"
                    Guid="{CA810124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
            <File Id="fil85729F855FDD131D6161043C08CB4543"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_dev_ConnectionStrings.config"/>
         </Component>
         <Component Id="cmpERG5974B57E1263C93B9B05FDFE715F"
                    Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A"
                    Guid="{ERGT50124-F44B-4EF5-986A-07FAA67434AB}">
            <File Id="fil8574324425555FDD131D6161043C08CB4543"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\TestBuild_prod_ConnectionStrings.config"/>
         </Component>
         <Component Id="cmp51A6C4030B563BC4A64DA99AED42D978"
                    Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A"
                    Guid="{CF063EF0-6926-4D21-B89D-BD71E0E926F7}">
            <File Id="fil1494493122AA1F38F8D2C11F93A8D4E8"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment.config"/>
         </Component>
         <Component Id="cmpDF354EF7DC6C98108D05886911231011"
                    Directory="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A"
                    Guid="{F912A8C7-1226-49D6-897F-1878A1607B16}">
            <File Id="fil1058EF5A5E46590311096FFC704CD243"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev"/>
         </Component>
         <Component Id="cmpE1C2EEC551696DCE99C2CAB9ED013C54"
                    Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286"
                    Guid="{A3D766EE-A488-468A-A7BF-DDB507B21299}">
            <File Id="fil2F90622E603C0AF703A504C3DE3A6201"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.config"/>
         </Component>
         <Component Id="cmpEBF2150BC59E378124B87AF387DA5519"
                    Directory="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286"
                    Guid="{16CF5D16-A551-4184-9E9D-772A9277941A}">
            <File Id="fil9241DCC3F781240AD979AAF25BF020F5"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\Deployment\Deployment.Dev.CSR.config"/>
         </Component>
         <Component Id="cmp3B36FD232E0AAD653B9259D5F2AC60A2"
                    Directory="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F"
                    Guid="{BF4A808E-AFBD-4F43-8F90-20E38639C8BD}">
            <File Id="filFD59C7E39C8BCA47D7ECEA7EBCA4E8FF"
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\controls\ReferAFriend\ReferAFriendInfo.ascx"/>
         </Component>
      </ComponentGroup>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="dir19836A556979704BCD883A1A4BC5ACCA">
         <Directory Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A" Name="App_Config"/>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="dir64C5FB989D956FBA878D608B754DE28A">
         <Directory Id="dir83BD7C94126520DBEDF76AF461521286" Name="Deployment"/>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="dir0370A1E873AC03CA5FA01FB090FBCEF4">
         <Directory Id="dirE4970414C520BB64F468385DC180508F" Name="ReferAFriend"/>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Haley your XSLT template works ,but it does not filter all required because of case sensitive for example input is 'dev' and does not give if the source has 'Dev'. Can you please revisit this Question and also I have modified the Question also as I need all the files in the result eliminating .prod,.UAT,.Test file sources and require all the remaining files. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user2066128 - I updated the answer to handle case. Have you tried modifying my answer to handle your new requirements?

Comment: Hi Daniel Haley the new requirement is for dev XSLT template ,if the input is 'dev' in XSLT template then output should filter out(eliminate) the file names that contain Test,UAT,prod only and give me files which contain 'dev' and the files which doesn't match with file names containing Test,UAT,prod. And yes tried modifying the template match but did not succeed .I tried like     <xsl:template match="NOT(@attr1) and NOT(@attr2) and NOT(@attr3)"> .Please let me know how to go on.

Comment: Hi Daniel I also tried match template as below but did not succeed. <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
  <xsl:key name="config-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.prod')]" use="@Id"/>
  <!--<!–Match and ignore .prod files–>-->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('config-search', @Id)]"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('config-search', @Id)]"/>
  Similarly for UAT and Test had tried

Comment: @user2066128 - What about the file `TestBuild_dev_ConnectionStrings.config`? You have that in your output, but it contains the string `Test`. Was this a mistake in your output example or would you really expect that file in the output?

Comment: TestBuild is just a sample for my testing .But in reality all the files will have dot extensions we will looking into like .Test,.test,.UAT,.uat,.prod,.Prod ... In my solution I was not able to use the Variable in expression for case sensitive check.I am waiting on you if you could come with better solution.

Comment: @user2066128 - Please see my update. I *think* it's now doing what you requested.

Comment: That worked  Daniel Haley . Thank you so much. And I have one more Question is their any way instead of hard coding the type to dev or prod .. can we pass type as parameter to xslt template? for below statement;   "C:\\bin\heat.exe" dir "C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb" -cg SCBUDirect -gg -t "C:\Workspaces\Chatra\FilterFiles.xslt" -out "C:\Workspaces\Chatra\WebSiteContent.wxs" -directoryid INSTALLLOCATION

Comment: @user2066128 - I'm not sure how to pass parameters with `heat.exe`, but `type` is a parameter and you should be able to pass it. I can with Saxon. You should check the docs for heat.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with below solution for dev Environment  but not sure it is efficient one.Similarly I need to create XSLT template for 'prod' ,'uat' & 'test'. But i am sure you will come with better solution. usually all the files have their dot extension of Environment.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
        xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:param name="type" select="'dev'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>


      <!--<!–Identity Transform–>-->
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
      <xsl:key name="prod" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'prod')]" use="@Id"/>
      <!--<!–Match and ignore .prod files–>-->
      <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('prod', @Id)]"/>
      <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('prod', @Id)]"/>

           <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
      <xsl:key name="Prod" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.Prod')]" use="@Id"/>
      <!--<!–Match and ignore .Prod files–>-->
      <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('Prod', @Id)]"/>
      <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('Prod', @Id)]"/>

          <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
      <xsl:key name="uat" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.uat')]" use="@Id"/>
      <!--<!–Match and ignore .uat files–>-->
      <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('uat', @Id)]"/>
      <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('uat', @Id)]"/>

           <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
      <xsl:key name="UAT" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.UAT')]" use="@Id"/>
      <!--<!–Match and ignore .UAT files–>-->
      <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('UAT', @Id)]"/>
      <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('UAT', @Id)]"/>

           <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
      <xsl:key name="Test" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.Test')]" use="@Id"/>
      <!--<!–Match and ignore .Test files–>-->
      <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('Test', @Id)]"/>
      <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('Test', @Id)]"/>


               <!--<!–Set up keys for ignoring various file types–>-->
      <xsl:key name="test" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.test')]" use="@Id"/>
      <!--<!–Match and ignore .test files–>-->
      <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('test', @Id)]"/>
      <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('test', @Id)]"/>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```